# Reports are not opened properly in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I deployed reports in my local machine.
My problem is When i opened the reports in google chrome Report in not displayed.

Can any one help me Why its not opened in Google Chrome?

Appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Comment: So I assume when you open your SSRS report to IE it is functioning? What is your coding environment (Visual Studio Version)?

Comment: Hi Christian,When i deployed SSRS reports into my local machine.Defaults it opens in Internet Explorer,Here No problem working its good.

See,When I copied Report Manager URL and try to  open in Google Chrome,Here Reports opened.

My problem is ,When i opened the reports in google chrome,Report in not displayed,
plz tell me the where is problem going on?

Comment: Are you opening the `RDLC` file directly?

Comment: No,I Copied The Report Mangaer URL and trying to open in Google Chrome

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Report Manager (Native mode)? If so, Report Manager supports IE only:
if you refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511(v=SQL.105).aspx)
what you describe sounds like a known issue when using WebKit browsers (Chrome) with Report Manager.

Reference:

[SQL 2008 Report Not Showing in Google Chrome](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/492ac295-9bf0-4ea4-b418-7b344f9c51f3).

Comment: Hi Christian, How we know am using Report Manager(Native Mode) or not? Please help am new to SSRS.

Comment: You can refer [to this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522825.aspx)